# Conditional table reference

Tags: postgresql, referential-integrity

I have a table `tree`:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
| 0    | tree1 |
| 1    | tree2 |
| 2    | tree3 |
| 3    | tree4 |
+------+-------+
```

A table `pen`:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
| 0    | pen1 |
| 1    | pen2 |
| 2    | pen3 |
| 3    | pen4 |
+------+------+
```

And a third table `task` that "attaches" a task to either a tree or a pen:

```
+------+------+-------+
| type | id   | name  |
+------+------+-------+
| 0    | 1    | foo   |
| 0    | 2    | bar   |
| 1    | 1    | fee   |
| 1    | 2    | beer  |
+------+------+-------+
```

When `type` is 0, it means `id` references a `tree`. When `type` is 1, it references a `pen` (and so on with many different tables).

How can I do this and ensure referential integrity?

Comment: Look at [Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html). Using it you could to create one base table for references and inherit from it both `tree` and `pen` tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a bridge table for task-tree and anther one for task-pen.

> ```
> create table tree 
> (
>     tree_id int primary key,
>     name text
> );
>
> create table pen
> (
>     pen_id int primary key,
>     name text
> );
>
> create table task
> (
>     task_id int primary key,
>     name text
> );
>
> create table task_tree
> (
>     task_id int references task (task_id) on update cascade,
>     tree_id int references tree (tree_id) on update cascade, 
>     primary key (task_id, tree_id)
> );
>
> create table task_pen
> (
>     task_id int references task (task_id) on update cascade,
>     pen_id int references pen (pen_id) on update cascade,
>     primary key (task_id, pen_id)
> );
>
> insert into tree values (1, 'tree1'),(2, 'tree2'),(3, 'tree3');
> insert into pen values (1, 'pen1'),(2, 'pen2'),(3, 'pen3');
> insert into task values (1, 'task1'),(2, 'task2');
> insert into task_tree values (1, 1),(2, 3),(1,2);
> insert into task_pen values (1, 2),(2, 2);
> ```

> ```
> select   tk.task_id, 
>          tk.name, 
>          array_agg(tr.name) as tree, 
>          array_agg(pn.name) as pen
> from     task tk
> join     task_tree tkt
> on       tkt.task_id = tk.task_id
> join     task_pen tkp
> on       tkp.task_id = tk.task_id
> join     tree tr
> on       tr.tree_id = tkt.tree_id
> join     pen pn
> on       pn.pen_id = tkp.pen_id
> group by tk.task_id, tk.name
> ```
>
> ```
> task_id | name  | tree          | pen        
> ------: | :---- | :------------ | :----------
>       1 | task1 | {tree1,tree2} | {pen2,pen2}
>       2 | task2 | {tree3}       | {pen2}
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5c210592b012e21e4c88a0a545b31441)*

**Update**

If, as per comments, you prefer to use a single task table with two fields, tree_id and pen_id, you can set referential integrity in this way:

I've added a check constraint that ensures that one of tree_id, pen_id is null:

```
alter table task 
    add constraint ck_one_in_two_must_be_null check(tree_id is null or pen_id is null);
```

> ```
> create table tree 
> (
>     tree_id int primary key,
>     name text
> );
>
> create table pen
> (
>     pen_id int primary key,
>     name text
> );
>
> create table task
> (
>     task_id int primary key,
>     name text,
>     tree_id int references tree (tree_id) on update cascade on delete restrict,
>     pen_id int references pen (pen_id) on update cascade on delete restrict
> );
>
> alter table task 
> add constraint ck_one_in_two_must_be_null check(tree_id is null or pen_id is null);
>
> insert into tree values (1, 'tree1'),(2, 'tree2'),(3, 'tree3');
> insert into pen values (1, 'pen1'),(2, 'pen2'),(3, 'pen3');
> insert into task values (1, 'task1', 1, null),(3, 'task3', null, 3);
> ```

> ```
> select    tk.task_id, 
>           tk.name,
>           tr.tree_id,
>           tr.name as tree_name,
>           pn.pen_id,
>           pn.name as pen_name
> from      task tk
> left join tree tr
> on        tr.tree_id = tk.tree_id
> left join pen pn
> on        pn.pen_id = tk.pen_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> task_id | name  | tree_id | tree_name | pen_id | pen_name
> ------: | :---- | ------: | :-------- | -----: | :-------
>       1 | task1 |       1 | tree1     |   null | null    
>       3 | task3 |    null | null      |      3 | pen3
> ```

> ```
> insert into task values (2, 'task2', 2, 3);
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  new row for relation "task" violates check constraint "ck_one_in_two_must_be_null"
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, task2, 2, 3).
> ```

> ```
> insert into task values (4, 'task4', 4, null);
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  insert or update on table "task" violates foreign key constraint "task_tree_id_fkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (tree_id)=(4) is not present in table "tree".
> ```

> ```
> insert into task values (5, 'task5', null, 6);
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  insert or update on table "task" violates foreign key constraint "task_pen_id_fkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (pen_id)=(6) is not present in table "pen".
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aa17a4af716b802965b1f143a5c7176f)*

Comment: This looks like a very good solution ! However, in my case I want to prevent a `task` to be to multiple _things_. It's either one `pen`, either one `tree`. How can I ensure referential integrity with those constraints ?

Comment: @Narann I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks ! My problem is still with `task_id` `2` which is connected to multiple entities (`tree2` AND `pen3`). `insert into task values (2, 'task2', 2, 3);` should raise an error. How can I ensure mutual exclusion?

Comment: I've added a check constraint, have a look

Answer (score 2):

Creating a table task adding a refer id field for each referred table, in this way:

- type : I prefer something as 'tree', 'pen'. Use an enum for this: ENUM('tree', 'pen');
- tree_id : int (it can be NULL), that refers to tree table;
- pen_id : int (it can be NULL), that refers to pen table;
- name : varchar;

Some test data:

```
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| type | tree_id | pen_id | name  |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| tree | 1       | NULL   | foo   |
| tree | 2       | NULL   | bar   |
| pen  | NULL    | 1      | fee   |
| pen  | NULL    | 2      | beer  |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I ensure referential integrity from a PostgreSQL stand point ?

Comment: Linking each referential field to respective table. task.tree_id to tree.id and task.pen_id to pen.id, in NO_ACTION or CASCADE or RESTRICT mode (as you need).

Comment: But `| tree | 1       | 1      | foo   |` will still be "valid" for PostgreSQL while it doesn't make sense in my use case. No?

Comment: Exactly, it is only a developer error, but referential integrity is respected.

Comment: i don't like this approach very much because if you need more tables (say 10), you'll need 10 columns. The constraint can be enforced by the way, with `CHECK (pen_id IS NOT NULL AND tree_id IS NULL or pen_is IS NULL AND tree_is IS NOT NULL)`. Or a bit more compact: `CHECK ( (pen_id IS NOT NULL)::int + (tree_id IS NOT NULL)::int = 1)`. The second way is more easier to be changed for many (10) columns.

Comment: @FabrizioCaldarelli the point of RI is to not allow any such invalid data, irrelevant if they come from developers/applications/users.

Comment: @Narann: If you are only ever going to have two references using this approach, here's a very compact PostgreSQL-compatible CHECK constraint specifically for two columns that will ensure one is always null and the other not: `CHECK ( (tree_id IS NULL) <> (pen_id IS NULL) )`.